# Certificate question (pkcs7)

Tags: certificate, pkcs#7

Accoring to the PKCS#7 standard certificate has some definite attributes. But I didn't find any information about the following:

1. What is OID?
2. What is RDN?
3. What is the format of Public Key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PKCS#7 and X.509 Certificates are both encoded in [ASN.1](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/asn1/introduction/).

- OID (Object Identifiers) is a basic ASN.1 type used for referencing objects in a unique and universal way. For instance, the OID 2.5.4.3 references [commonName](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/2.5.4.3.html).
- RDN (Relative Distinguished Name) is one element of a DN.
- In PKCS#7 and X.509, the format of the Public Key depends on the algorithm. As an example, the ASN.1 schema for RSA public keys is

  ```
  RSAPublicKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER   -- e
  }
  ```